# Challenge: MS Excel VBA Programming for the Absolute Beginner

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm learning VBA using a combination of VBA For Dummies and the above mentioned book. The latter, presents a simple challenge (Challenge 2, Chapter 2) that I'd like to ask some for some feedback about.

The challenge is as follows:

> Place a Command Button control on a worksheet and write a program in the Click()
>   event procedure that increments a variable by 5 with every click of the mouse.
>   Output the value of this variable in a message box.

I've put together the following the code snippet in response:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim AddClick As Integer

AddClick = Range("A1").Value
AddClick = AddClick + 5
Range("A1").Value = AddClick

MsgBox AddClick

End Sub
```

Although the code works, I'm pretty sure there's a way to eliminate the use of 'Range("A1").Value' to base the 'AddClick' variable on. How would I go about doing this?

*Update: Thanks to Cody Gray's suggestion (http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5854605.html), I've revised the code to the following - which now works just fine (edited for further simplication):*

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Static AddClick As Integer

AddClick = AddClick + 5

MsgBox AddClick

End Sub
```

Simples. Thanks again Cody.

Comment: Have you come across a chapter or section on scope and lifetime of variables? If so, I suspect that the exercise is about that.

Comment: Completely irrelevant to your question: You don't need the parenthesis around the `AddClick` parameter in your `MsgBox` call. If you want to use parenthesis, you can use the `Call` syntax instead: `Call MsgBox(AddClick)`. See [Eric Lippert's blog entry on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) for all the gory details.

Comment: Edited, noted for future reference and very grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both previous samples are wrong I think. The correct version is below:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Static AddClick As Integer
   AddClick = AddClick + 5
   MsgBox AddClick
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a note:  Static avoids the variable to be reset at end of Sub. No need to give an initial value here, since an integer is ALWAYS initialised to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Define the variable at module level.
Doing this will increase the scope of the variable from procedure to the module.

Replace the existing code with this one.

```
Option Explicit
Dim AddClick As Integer

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   AddClick = 0
   AddClick = AddClick + 5

   MsgBox (AddClick)
End Sub
```

Note: Defining the variable at procedure level will limit its life.
i.e. the variable won't be accessible outside the scope of the procedure.

Comment: While this is completely correct, and probably gives you a better idea of what's actually happening behind the scenes, I have a suspicion that whatever book/tutorial that the asker is reading has introduced `Static` variables and expects you to try using them in this example. Here's a run-down of their use in VB 6 (which should be very straightforward to apply to VBA): http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5854605.html

Comment: @Cody Gray - thank you very much. I knew there was something simple I'd overlooked. I'll post the revised code snippet in the interest of closure. Thanks again.

Comment: Isn't it more likely that variable scope would be taught before statics?